# Is there an R function to transform rows into vectors based on a grouping of three variables?

Tags: r

As of right now my data is in one huge list and every three rows of data contains information for the same observation. This means that they need to stay together as a group when I manipulate the data frame. Here is the problem I am facing, I want to transform my data from rows to columns, but I only want three columns (I.e., a column for each type of information).

To illustrate this is my data frame now:

```
1
00:09:49.350 --> 00:09:49.800
Hello, good.
2
00:09:54.750 --> 00:09:55.350
Customer: Morning.
3
00:09:56.100 --> 00:09:56.670
Morning.
```

And here is what I am hoping for:

```
1      00:09:49.350 --> 00:09:49.800      Hello, good.
2      00:09:54.750 --> 00:09:55.350      Customer: Morning.
3      00:09:56.100 --> 00:09:56.670      Morning.
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you provide your data using `dput`? `dput(head(df))` would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `cbind`

```
#sample data
df <- structure(list(X1 = c("1", "00:09:49.350 --> 00:09:49.800", "Hello, good.", 
"2", "00:09:54.750 --> 00:09:55.350", "Customer: Morning.", "3", 
"00:09:56.100 --> 00:09:56.670", "Morning.")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

now proceed like this

```
n1 <- nrow(df)
as.data.frame(cbind(df[1:n1 %% 3 == 1,], df[1:n1 %% 3 == 2,], df[1:n1 %% 3 == 0,]))

  V1                            V2                 V3
1  1 00:09:49.350 --> 00:09:49.800       Hello, good.
2  2 00:09:54.750 --> 00:09:55.350 Customer: Morning.
3  3 00:09:56.100 --> 00:09:56.670           Morning.
```

**Explanation** Using mod function i.e. `%%` in `R` we can easily group select every third row starting from first , second and third row respectively and lastly `cbind` them all together.  `as.data.frame()` will cause the result into a data.frame, as desired, which is optional.

**Hereafter you can easily manipulate your column types**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

# the data as list just for explanation 
my_list <- tibble(1,
"00:09:49.350 --> 00:09:49.800", "Hello, good.", 2, "00:09:54.750 --> 00:09:55.350", 
"Customer: Morning.", 3, "00:09:56.100 --> 00:09:56.670", "Morning." )

# list to dataframe: **here replace my_list with your list**
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(my_list), nrow=length(my_list), byrow=TRUE))

# new dataframe
df1 <- df %>% 
  rename_at( 1, ~"Col1" ) %>%  # rename column
  mutate(id = rep(1:3, each=3)) %>%  # group id for the data
  group_by(id) %>% 
  slice(2:n()) %>% # remove first row in each group
  mutate(Col2 = lead(Col1)) %>% 
  slice(1:(n()-1)) %>%  # remove last row in each group
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-id)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, is there a way I can do this without having to list all my data in a tibble. I have 10,000 rows in 34 data files I have to re-organize?

Comment: See my edit. You can omit the tibble part. It is just to get your data to work with. Replace the name of my_list with the name of your list name in this code `df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(my_list), nrow=length(my_list), byrow=TRUE))
`.